# passing data to another page from nlevel menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, query-string

I have a multi level menu with asp.net c# that it gets its items from the database table. my table has items: menuID, menuname, description, parentID. my code is like below.

```
<asp:Menu ID="menuBar" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="80%"
                    onmenuitemclick="menuBar_MenuItemClick" Height="28px">

                </asp:Menu>
```

and the code behind is:

```
public void Connect()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnstring"].ConnectionString);
    }

    private void getMenu()
    {

        Connect();
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string sql = "Select * from tbl_WebMenu";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        DataRow[] drowpar = dt.Select("ParentID=" + 0);

        foreach (DataRow dr in drowpar)
        {
            menuBar.Items.Add(new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(), dr["MenuID"].ToString()));
        }

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select("ParentID >" + 0))
        {
            MenuItem mnu = new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(), dr["MenuID"].ToString());


            mnu.Enabled = true;

        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

I have a page that it's name is description.aspx. when clicking on the one of menu items, I want to redirect to description page and show the description of the selected menu item. I think I should use querystring, like on menuitem click: responce.redirect(description.aspx?ID=something) the problem is that I don't know how to get the ID of the selected item of menu and pass it to the description page.
please help me.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters as Value when adding items to the menu and then retrieve these in on click event handler.

```
protected void menuBar_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("SomePAge.aspx?ID=" + e.CommandArgument);
    }
```

Comment: Excuse me, how can I add parameters as value for the menu? can you help me about this?